# Preference with in-line options

Tags: android, preferences

I've created a PReference Screen which lets the user manage a series of elements marked by himself as "favorites". I create a Preference category then fill it up with options dynamically, taking them from a sqlite database. This is a screencap:

[image]

And this is a screen mockup of what I want to achieve:

[image]

That is, I want for every preference item to add an in-line remove option that allows users to directly remove favorites.

The problem is I don't know how to do this, and I've seen no similar examples. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Android provides an easy means to implement preferences screen, but standard android ListPreference does not provide an easy way to display an image for each item if the list. To add the images to the Android ListPreference, we need to use a custom xml attribute

Here is some example that may help you

http://www.cmwmobile.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=12

[How to add icons to Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765186/how-to-add-icons-to-preference)

Answer (score 0):

To delete prefrence from prefrence screen you you can refer this Link : [How to determine which preference item from custom layout button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702267/how-to-determine-which-preference-item-from-custom-layout-button-click)

Comment: It's more about adding an icon then detecting the click on that icon, than removing the preference dynamically

Comment: Ok now the problem comes with me creating the preferences dynamically, it seems that to use that code I must use an AttributeSet that comes from XML definitions (which I don't have since I create everything by code).